# Падение при возврате из функции const char*

Tags: c++, строки, функции

Имеется данный код

```
const char* get_msg(){
    const char str[] = "get_msg";
    return str;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("%s\n", get_msg());
}
```

При компиляции выдается

> warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]

и естественно при выполнении приложение крашится.
Я понимаю почему это происходит, ведь строка была на стеке и он уничтожается после того как функция вернула значение.

Однако если функцию переписать так

```
const char* get_msg(){
    return "get_msg";
}
```

То нет ни варнингов ни падения. Меня интересует, как работает *return "get_msg";* ?
Получается эта строка находится на стеке? Или где? Ведь эта строка по логике должна "исчезать" после возврата функции.

Компилирую так: gcc main.c -o main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строка `"get_msg"` храниться в программе как статические данные в отделе, защищённом от изменений.
Приблизительно так :

```asm
__Stroka1234 : "get_msg"
```

Стандарт говорит про это так :

> Evaluating a string-literal results in a string literal object with static storage duration, initialized from the given characters as specified above. Whether all string-literals are distinct (that is, are stored in non overlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified.
> [Note 7 : The effect of attempting to modify a string-literal is undefined. — end note]

> Вычисление строкового литерала приводит к созданию объекта строкового литерала со статической продолжительностью хранения, инициализированного из заданных символов, как указано выше. Не указано, являются ли все строковые литералы различными (то есть хранятся в неперекрывающихся объектах) и приводят ли последовательные вычисления строкового литерала к одному и тому же или к другому объекту.
> [Примечание 7: Эффект от попытки изменить строковый литерал не определен. — заключительная нота]

Строка `const char str[] = "get_msg";` как копия храниться в стеке. И после окончания работы функции обращение к строке приведёт к неопределённому поведению.

А если вы возвращаете адрес `return "get_msg";` статической безымянной строки, то можете к ней обращаться всегда, только не изменять.

Comment: То есть как я понял эта строка находится где-то в секции .data

Comment: в отделе `.rodata` с адресами примерно такими : 0x00004000 , а стек имеет адрес около такого 0x7fff0000

Comment: Вопрос не в тему, а где можно почитать о том, как и где хранятся различные данные и по каким адрессам? Например stacktrace пишет где было произведено падение. Было бы удобно в логах видеть что именно привело к сигфоултам

Answer (score 5):

Здесь

```
const char str[] = "get_msg";
```

выделяется место для массива `str` на стеке, он заполняется строкой `"get_msg"` (строковый литерал копируется в массив в стеке). Потом функция возвращает адрес этого массива.

Тут же

```
return "get_msg";
```

возвращается адрес места в некоторой памяти, где хранятся строковые литералы (упрощенно, это место зависит от компилятора, операционки и т.д.). Т.е. этот адрес будет указывать на действительное место в памяти, в то время как в предыдущем `return` возвращается указатель на место в стеке.

Answer (score 1):

Код

```
const char* get_msg(){
    return "get_msg";
}
```

эквивалентен коду

```
const char* get_msg(){
    static const char str[] = "get_msg";
    return str;
}
```

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin зачем нормальный ответ с кодом публиковать в комментарии?

Comment: @user207200, ну вот смотрю я на текст вопроса. в нём вот такие вопросы задаёт его автор: `Меня интересует, как работает return "get_msg"; ? Получается эта строка находится на стеке? Или где?`. т.е., данный ответ на данные вопросы напрямую не отвечает. да, возможно, он отвечает косвенно (я не могу это оценить как не-программист). но в таком случае имеет смысл написать в тексте ответа, каким же именно образом он относится к заданному вопросу(-ам).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin согласен, ответ косвенный. Но тут более уместна рекомендация автору _постараться давать более развернутые ответы_, а не публиковать в виде комментария.